# How do I set the type of geometry when creating a SQL table?

Tags: sql, enterprise-geodatabase, geometry, sql-server

The table I am trying to recreate has these properties

```
Data Type      File Geodatabase Feature Class
Feature Type   Simple
Geometry Type  Polygon    <<<< WHAT I WANT TO RECREATE
```

My target SQL table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyAggregateTable](
    [OBJECTID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SHAPE] [geometry] NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    ...
```

And the resulting properties are:

```
Data Type      Enterprise Database Feature Class
Feature Type   Simple
Geometry type  Any         <<<< NOT THE SAME!
```

FURTHER PROGRESS / EDIT

Now I have discovered that I can manipulate the geometry type by using the ArcCatalog App. I can change the Type to "Polygon Features" manually on the FeatureClass properties - but it's not permanent. As soon as I exit, it 'forgets'.

Then I dicovered that if I manually "Load Data" in the ArcCatalog App, the FeatureClass properties are set, the data is loaded, and we are good to go.

However, if I flush the table, (not DROP), the geometry type reverts back.

So basically a SearchCursor / InsertCursor approach does not work >>> it has to be done manually.

Comment: SQL is a language; SQL Server is an RDBMS.  If you register the table with the Enterprise geodatabase, then ArcGIS will know (because that's one of the parameters).

Comment: I hear you, but the quirks of my environment here is that I'm not "register the table with the Enterprise geodatabase".

Comment: Query Layers discover the geometry type by doing an initial SELECT (and if the table is empty, you *must* provide the geometry type).  If the feature class is registered, it has a place to remember the geometry type, otherwise it must rediscover with each new connection.  You can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually managed to do it as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE .... (
    [gps_polygons] [geometry] NULL,
....
]
GO

DECLARE @g geometry;   
SET @g = geometry::STPolyFromText('POLYGON ((5 5, 10 5, 10 10, 5 5))', 4167);  

INSERT INTO .....(
...
gps_geometry, 
.....

VALUES (
....
@g.ToString()
....
```

Whilst that record exists in the non enterprise registered geodatabase, the geometry is polygon as a I wanted.

Does not sound very robust to me, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

In the instance of ONLY using SQL Server, it appears that the geometry type is not stored at the table level, but rather at the record level.
See here
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/spatial-types-geometry-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#registering-the-geometry-type

```
    IF OBJECT_ID ( 'dbo.SpatialTable', 'U' ) IS NOT NULL   
    DROP TABLE dbo.SpatialTable  
GO  
  
CREATE TABLE SpatialTable   
    ( id int IDENTITY (1,1),  
    GeomCol1 geometry,   
    GeomCol2 AS GeomCol1.STAsText() );  
GO  
  
INSERT INTO SpatialTable (GeomCol1)  
VALUES (geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (100 100, 20 180, 180 180)', 0));  
  
INSERT INTO SpatialTable (GeomCol1)  
VALUES (geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 150 0, 150 150, 0 150, 0 0))', 0));  
GO
```

As you can see above, a line and a polygon record are inserted into the same table. ST_GeometryType is then run at the record level, to return the geometry type.

Note that the above info is for standalone MS SQL database. Your introduction of ArcGIS introduces a slight element of complexity.

So the answer to your question is that the geometry type is not set at the table level, but is determined by each individual record, which MS SQL allows to be anything for each record.